# Image is not setting properly in the ImageView inside a CardView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-cardview, android-scrollview

I am new in android app development. I am developing an app in which I want to set a image of full width but it is taking so much space. I am not understanding, why it is taking so much space? Image URl([full.jpg](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=donut%20png&tbm=isch&imgil=ryz8cnz4DPEiVM%253A%253B0oTOQomfCr6e5M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.pngpix.com%25252Fdownload%25252Ftag%25252Fdoughnut&source=iu&pf=m&fir=ryz8cnz4DPEiVM%253A%252C0oTOQomfCr6e5M%252C_&usg=__eT5PiFpwern_ULiqJWfJBtb5Lrg%3D&biw=1279&bih=585&ved=0ahUKEwj539-ph8TTAhWFs48KHQWhCGoQyjcILw&ei=JJYBWfm9BIXnvgSFwqLQBg#tbm=isch&q=full%20width%20images&imgrc=-_QsbbnE_TOSbM:))

My xml code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="litifer.awesome.game.cardview.MainActivity"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cardView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cardView1Text"
            android:text="Notifications"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cardView1Text1"
                android:text="we will let you know about great content when big news happens or when your magazines arrive"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cardView1Text2"
                android:text="SETTINGS                GOT IT"
                android:paddingLeft="160dp"
                android:textColor="#f2f"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="HIGHLIGHTS"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Recommended based on your interests"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:src="@drawable/full"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your `ImageView` and you could also use `android:scaleType="center_inside"`. More details [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide).

Comment: When I applied android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" it is working properly

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:scaleType="center_inside"` property of Imageview.